# MVC DropDownListFor is not showing spaces added to values in list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this dropdown in a view which I fill with values from the DB.  I am combining some the values and trying to align them:

```
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            string loc = dr.IsNull("STATEGEOG_LOC_NAME") ? "" : dr["STATEGEOG_LOC_NAME"].ToString();
                            if (loc.Length < maxloc)
                                loc = SetStringLength(loc, maxloc);
                            string name = dr.IsNull("NAME") ? "" : dr["NAME"].ToString();
                            if (name.Length < maxname)
                                name = SetStringLength(name, maxname);
                            string mtf = dr.IsNull("MTF_CODE") ? "" : dr["MTF_CODE"].ToString();
                            if (mtf.Length < maxmtf)
                                mtf = SetStringLength(mtf, maxmtf);
                            TextValuePair model = new TextValuePair()
                            {
                                Value = dr.IsNull("IEN") ? "" : dr["IEN"].ToString(),
                                Text = loc + " " + name + " " + mtf
                            };
                            countries.Add(model);
                        }

    private static string SetStringLength(string input, int len)
    {
        return input.PadRight(len, ' ');
    }
```

The values I compare simply find the longest of the values in the DB and pad the current value with spaces to make it than long.  I see each line like this:

```
 "MARYLAND                               10 CSH (FT MEADE MD)                          A11B1 "
```

I send it to the view with this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAllGeoLocations()
    {
        return Json(Repository.GetGeoLocationList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And it is loaded into the DDL like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllGeoLocations")',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ddlLocation").empty();
            $.each(data, function (Value, Text) {
                var opt = '<option value=' + Text.Value + '>' + Text.Text + '</option>';
                $("#ddlLocation").append(opt);
            });
        }
    });
```

And each value I check when I debug the page shows the proper padding.  But when the dropdown is clicked, the padding goes away.  Can anyone tell me why?

When I use the debugger in the page I see the values loading into the DDL like this:

```
 "<option value=6005>VIRGINIA                               1 DENTAL SQ/SGD                               F1783 </option>"
```

But the dropdown show this:

[image]

Comment: What is `maxLoc`? try `&nbsp` to add space.

Answer (score 1):

Don't blame MVC / Razor for that. 
It is the browser. 
Try to replace spaces in your option-value with

```
"&nbsp;"
```

Try to use:

```
var opt = '<option value=' + Text.Value + '>' + Text.Text.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;") + '</option>';
```

In your $.each look.

This will force the whitespaces.

Comment: That does not work either, I used var text = Text.Text.replace(" ", "&nbsp;") and all I get is one single &nbsp; in the string.

Comment: Yes, my fault. Updated the answer!

Comment: Put this in the page?

Comment: Yes, for your view. But you have to set it in your DataRow-iteration: TextValuePair model = new TextValuePair(){... Text = Regex. ... }

Comment: Okay. So, get back to your previous version. Try to use the JS-Regex. I will update my answer. This will be the prefered solution, because the view has to handle this specific display-problem, not the controller/backend.

Comment: I try this:  var opt = '<option value=' + Text.Value + '>' + @Regex.Replace(text, " ", "&nbsp;") + '</option>';  and the 'text' word is red underlined and error says the name text does not exist.  Plus I have to add @using System.Text.RegularExpressions to my view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132920/discussion-between-faustserbe-and-dean-depue).